# Python3.6 + Postgresql how to put VARIABLES to SQL query?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.6

I got something like this:

> cur.execute("INSERT INTO name VALUES(HERE_IS_VARIABLE,'string',int,'string')")

Stuff with %s (like in python 2.*) not working.
I got errors, which tells me that im trying to use "column name" in place where i put my variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using f-Strings and separating out the statement from the execution:

`statement = f"INSERT INTO name VALUES({VARIABLE_NAME},'string',int,'string')" 
cur.execute(statement)`

You might also want to try with '' around {VARIABLE_NAME}: '{VARIABLE_NAME}'

In f-strings, the expressions in {} get evaluated and their values inserted into the string.

By separating out the statement you can print it and see if the string is what you were expecting.

Note, the f-string can be used within the cur.execute function, however I find it more readable to separate out.

In python3.6+ this is a better way of formatting strings then with %s.

If this does not solve the problem, more information will help debug:

what is the name table's schema?
what variable / value are you trying to insert?
what is the exact error you are given?

Comment: f string are not escaped by default. This is dangerous.